# redirect output of tee and grep for multiple logfiles

Tags: shell-script, grep, pipe

Redirecting output from a script STDOUT + STDERR to`Logfile 1` and a grep to `Logfile 2`

```
./run_test.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/log1.log | (grep 'START|END') > /var/log/myscripts.log
```

How can I make this work?

I tried the different syntax, but it did not works.

The output will be redirected only to the first log. The second log is empty.

```
./run.sh 2>&1 | tee -a ~/log1.log | grep 'Start' > /var/log/myscripts.log
./run.sh 2>&1 | tee -a ~/log1.log | egrep 'Start' > /var/log/myscripts.log
./run.sh 2>&1 | tee -a ~/log1.log | grep -E 'Start' > /var/log/myscripts.log
```

`log1.log` contains the output. `myscripts.log` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need (or want) the parentheses there. Also, the `grep` syntax for logical OR is `grep 'foo\|bar`. You need to escape the `|` unless you use `-E`. So, any of these will work:

```
./run_test.sh 2>&1 | tee -a log1.log | grep 'START\|END' > myscripts.log
```

or

```
./run_test.sh 2>&1 | tee -a log1.log | grep -E 'START|END' > myscripts.log
```

or

```
./run_test.sh 2>&1 | tee -a log1.log | grep -P 'START|END' > myscripts.log
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you tried is more or less correct.

- The `grep` pattern does not work this way. The following ways would work:

  ```
  egrep 'START|END'
  grep -E 'START|END'
  grep 'START\|END'
  ```
- parentheses around the `grep` call are not needed. They would start a subshell.

Final command:

```
./run_test.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/log1.log | grep 'START\|END' > /var/log/myscripts.log
```